# How do I calculate a linear equation for my table?

Tags: math, interpolation, equation

I am writing a program that does some unit conversions from a Brix scale to some other units.

The program works by displaying a scale to the user, and allows the user to click on the scale to select a Brix measurement.  The range I am using is between 1 & 30.

The problem is, the scale is not linear.  As the Brix number gets higher, more space is between each increment, so I need to figure out the linear equation that would allow me to translate the y position of the user input to the number on the scale.

I made the following chart to show the correlation between the brix value and the y-position of the user click (in pixels):

```
Brix | PosY  
=====|=====  
  0  |   0  
  1  |  10  
  5  |  50
 10  | 100    
 12  | 123    
 15  | 155    
 16  | 167    
 19  | 201    
 21  | 225    
 24  | 262    
 26  | 287    
 28  | 314    
 30  | 340
```

Basically, I need to be able to figure out Brix, given PosY.  How do I determine the equation to use?

Comment: so how are you able to calculate the PosY and PosX in the first place?

Comment: from the user input, posY is where the cursor is clicked, so to get these values, I clicked on 0,1,5,10,12, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interpolation in non-linear situations where one doesn't know the exact equation, people generally uses a **cubic spline** fit and interpolation.  Depending on the accuracy that you need, you could possible just get by with a **piece-wise linear** fit; that is, do independent linear interpolations between successive pairs of points.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your data is "almost" linear:

```
  Brix(PosY) := 0.092 * PosY
```

[image]

If you really want a better approximation (I think that is improbable), you may try:

```
  Brix(PosY) := 0.10370203*Posy + 0.051016908*Cos[(227.63841*Posy)] - 
                0.056852482*Cos[(0.10305045*Posy)] - 4.6300302*10^-5*Posy^2
```

Which gives:

[image]

I got the last one using least squares via **[Eureqa](http://ccsl.mae.cornell.edu/eureqa)**